# How to remove "@" from a formula which comes from a script in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, runtime-error

```
newWs.Range("AH2:AH500").Formula = "=TRIM(TEXTJOIN("","", TRUE, IF((C2:AD2=""A"")+(C2:AD2=""WO"")+(C2:AD2=""HO"")+(C2:AD2=""L(CL)""), TEXT($C$1:$AD$1, ""DD/MM/YYYY""), """")))
```

I have this very simple formula in my VBS Script but as soon as I run it, it adds an `@` in the formula which gives me a value error in the sheet. This is the formula that I get in the output

```
newWs.Range("AH2:AH500").Formula = "=TRIM(TEXTJOIN("","", TRUE, IF((@C2:AD2=""A"")+(@C2:AD2=""WO"")+(@C2:AD2=""HO"")+(@C2:AD2=""L(CL)""), TEXT($C$1:$AD$1, ""DD/MM/YYYY""), """")))
```

Comment: Use `Formula2` not `Formula`